# SQL Convert Rows to Columns without aggreagate or pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert rows to columns . Please look at the below sample:

```
colname  |  data1 |   data2

---------|--------|------------------------------------
     a   |    1   |
     a   |    2   |
     a   |    3   |
     b   |    4   |
     b   |    5   |
     c   |        |     6  
     c   |        |     7
```

I want the output as:

```
      a  |   b     |   c

---------|--------|------------------------------------
     1   |        |
     2   |        |
     3   |        |
         |    4   |
         |    5   |
         |        |     6  
         |        |     7
```

Could anyone please share your ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far??

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done without a `PIVOT` unless you use a lot of hardcoding that will break as soon as your data changes.  Why can you not use a `PIVOT`?

Comment: If you just merely avoiding SUM just because your data type is in "string", you could still use PIVOT, here's a nice article, http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-without-aggregation.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I guess you are using mysql and that is why you cannot use the mssql `pivot`. Have a look at e.g. [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really putting rows to columns.  So it's not a PIVOT that's needed.
You just want to show values in some columns depending on what value colname has.
A [CASE WHEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) can be used for that.

```
select 
case when colname = 'a' then data1 end as a,
case when colname = 'b' then data1 end as b,
case when colname = 'c' then data2 end as c
from yourtable;
```